# Chaining functions that return promises in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

The idea is that I need to run multiple operations against the database, but only if I need to. For instance if there are no items to insert, then there is no insert call.

```
function dbOperations(params){
    functionInsert(params)
    .then(functionUpdate(params))
    .then(functionDelete(params))
    ...
}
```

then I have

```
function functionInsert(params){
  if (params){
    //DO a call against DB which returns a promise 
   return knex.insert().transacting(trx);
  }else{
    //if no params, no need to do anything, just let the next .then() fire next function
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
}
```

By having it like that, the code runs fine but when there are no `params` then I see this warning `Warning: .then() only accepts functions but was passed: [object Object]` so it's obvious I am doing something wrong.

How should this scenario be handled, when there are no params?

LE: for db access I am using `knex`. I've edited the functionInsert above.

Comment: Don't you have to wrap the blocks in `then` into some closure to make them execute only when `then` is called (as opposed to calling it immediately and passing the result to `then`)?  something like `.then( function(){ functionUpdate(params)})`

Comment: Looks like `functionUpdate` and/or `functionDelete` are returning object instead of function when there are no params.

Comment: The reason it works when `params` are present is that `functionInsert` does then not return a Promise, but a function that returns a Promise. `promiseFromORM` vs `promiseFromORM()`.  It probably works if you do `Promise.resolve` instead of `Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: @Thillo using it with `then(function...` generates blocking between operations. Maybe my functions are called in parallel and not one after the other? It is really important to have them run one after another do avoid deadlocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning itself is explaining. `.then` expects a function as its argument, but you're passing the result of the function `functionUpdate` instead.

You may want to wrap the statement(s) in anonymous functions instead, as pointed out by @Thilo in the comments:

```
function dbOperations(params){
    functionInsert(params)
      .then(() => functionUpdate(params))
      .then(() => functionDelete(params))
      ...
}
```

Comment: But then, you also need to fix the `if (params)` part to return `promiseFromORM()` instead of `promiseFromORM`.

Comment: @Thilo -- correct. That function should be called to get the promise returned to the chain.

Comment: I've added the detail that I am using `knex` for db calls if that adds any extra info. So `return knex.raw('insert into...')`

Comment: @31piy the problem with running it like you've answered is that I get blocking processes on my server, basically update query from`functionUpdate` can block `functionInsert` so to me this looks like they are executing in parallel maybe? I want tthe secon then() to execute only after the previous one completed successfully

Comment: @Alin -- The code that I wrote will make the promises to execute one-by-one. Means, `functionUpdate` will execute after `functionInsert` and `functionDelete` will execute after `functionUpdate`. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: @31piy yes that is what I want but it seems it doesn't execute that way. Or at least that is what I understand from the fact that I get deadlocks in the database... I'll add some logging to see what's happening

Comment: @Alin -- Did you change `return promiseFromORM;` to `return promiseFromORM();`?

Comment: I've added the edit above in the question, the return looks like `return knex.raw().transacting(trx)` or other methods of `knex`.

Comment: Culprit for locking was in my transaction, having update a row in 2 places during the same transaction. Thanks for the answer